# Snowflake performance test

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, performance-testing

I have an ETL pipeline which is scheduled in Airflow , the Airflow DAG calls the snowflake stored procedure .
The stored procedure reads the data from a view and writes into the table by performing 'Merge'

I am doing some changes in the pipeline by rewriting query in the view .
specifically , removing the filter in the view and applying in the stored proc .

How can I test this by not using any cache in snowflake .

I have tested with separate warehouses
I have tested with ALTER SESSION SET USE_CACHED_RESULT=FALSE;
I have checked the view's query plans.
I have tested the new pipeline via airflow DAG in non prod environment , but I am not able to fetch the query id of this pipeline in 'query history' table . to check the query plan .

How can I get the query ID of the non prod pipeline ?
and any suggestion's on the easy way of test ?

Answer (score 0):

1. While running this kind of tests you can set USE_CACHED_RESULT=FALSE on the user's level. Then you do not need to worry about setting it for the session.

```sql
    ALTER USER <your_test_user> SET USE_CACHED_RESULT=FALSE;
```

2. The queries generated by external apps might not appear in your query history if the filter is disabled. You can enable it. Go to Activity - Query History - Filters - Client generated statements. Plus make sure that if you use a different usernames for AirFlow and for UI, the respective filter is also set accordingly. See screenshot:

[image: See screenshot]